# NoClassDefFoundError happens at runtime when I use mutliple Java packages in a single Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, build-process, noclassdeffounderror

I did the following:

1. Create a working Android project (not a library or test project) in Eclipse.  It has a single package called X with an activity X.A.
2. Create a new Java package Y within the aforementioned project with at least one class Y.C.
3. Call Y.C from within X.A (that is, call something in the new package from the original package that previously works).
4. Build and run the Android project.

It builds fine, but throws NoClassDefFoundError on the first line using Y.C, saying it cannot find Y.C.  When I Refactor -> Move Y.C into package X (so it is now X.C), the runtime exception is no longer thrown.  What's wrong?

Vague hint: I've read that similar problems can happen when the build-time and runtime classpaths get out of sync somehow, but I haven't found yet how to troubleshoot or fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` when defining your activities you have to set the fully qualified class name for activities residing in a sub-package or even another package.

A fully qualified class name would be like `com.example.my.cool.app.Activity`. Alternatively when only working with sub-packages you can set it like this `android:name=".app1.AnotherActivity"` when your base-package looks like this `com.example.my.cool`.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't learned about AndroidManifest in-depth yet, so I'll do that next.  I don't have any activities in the second package (Y).

Comment: @apollodude217: Then there is no problem. Just import the needed class in your Activity you're trying to access it from and all it good.

Comment: If you mean to use "import Y.C;" in the source code file for X.A, then I have already done that, and it still throws at runtime when I call Y.C.

Comment: @apollodude217: And you are sure your classes don't extend Activity?

Comment: Alas!, I fixed the problem somewhere along the way, but forgot to answer, so I'll assume this is what went wrong.  (Shame on me!)